# Assign a Series with its index to a multiIndex dataframe with loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

With a dataframe of an index level of 2, either empty or filled with something:

```py
import pandas as pd
midx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]],
                     codes=[[],[]],
                     names=[u'var_name', u'modalities']
                    )
df = pd.DataFrame(index=midx)

df.loc[("foo","bar"),"A"]  = 3
df

### Returns
                       A
var_name modalities     
foo      bar         3.0
```

I want to assign the values of a series:

```py
s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=["a","b","c"])
```

Such that the results is:

```py
                       A
var_name modalities     
foo      bar         3.0
baz      a           1.0
         b           2.0
         c           3.O
```

How could I get that with `loc` or another solution ?

`df.loc[("baz", s.index), "A"] = s` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the method with `loc`.
My current solution is to use the `concat` method, which feels a bit unnatural to me (The first answer with a solution will get the checkmark).

##### Solution with concat

```py
import pandas as pd
midx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[],[]],
                     codes=[[],[]],
                     names=[u'var_name', u'modalities']
                    )
df = pd.DataFrame(index=midx)
df.loc[("foo","bar"),"A"]  = 3

s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=["a","b","c"], name="A")
s_midx =pd.concat([s], keys=["baz"])
df_s_midx=pd.DataFrame(s_midx) # Is there a way to avoid this?
pd.concat([df, df_s_midx])
```

There is probably a way to avoid converting the series `s_midx` to a dataframe, but I did not find it!